# Create custom page for each taxonomy

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type in which you can choose different taxonomies. This taxonomies are listed in the page of single custom post type. When clicking on one of this taxonomy, I would the user to be redirect to a specific taxonomy page that show different informations about that taxonomy.
How can I do that with word press?

I'm using bones framework.

There is no category.php in this framework.. So i found this file:

```
taxonomy-custom_cat.php
```

in which is written:

"This is the custom post type taxonomy template. If you edit the custom taxonomy name, you've got to change the name of this template to reflect that name change.

i.e. if your custom taxonomy is called

```
 register_taxonomy( 'shoes',
```

then your single template should be taxonomy-shoes.php"

I did it but it doesn't work

PS: the taxonomy is called "agenti-biodeteriogeni"

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make the copy of your category.php file and name it as your 'customposttype-category(taxonomy-name).php' this will display information of taxonomy like category.

Comment: Can you please tell me when your original post category is called then which page it will show?

Comment: one time just try shoes.php

Comment: nothing change, it always show me the "Oops, Post Not Found!" sentence.. it's like it doesn't read the shoes.php file

Comment: try taxonomy.php only nothing else